# Collecting a basic map in Java 8 streams API

Tags: java, java-stream

```
    Map<String, String> preFilteredKafkaRecords = kafkaRecordMap.entrySet().stream()
            .map(item -> getUrls(item.getKey(), item.getValue()))
            .filter(THING_1)
            .filter(THING_2)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    Map.Entry<String, String>::getKey, Map.Entry<String, String>::getValue));
```

`getUrls` - returns `Map<String, String>`

how can I collect this to a `Map<String, String>`? The first map returns a `Map<String, String>` but I can't get the compiler to stop complaining.

Comment: Does `getUrls()` return an `Entry`?

Comment: Map<String, String>, sorry should've clarified that.

Comment: Then how do you expect to call `Entry::getKey` on it?

Comment: I don't anymore...

Answer (score 3):

If `getUrls()` returns a `Map`, you can't collect it as an `Entry`. If the idea is to combine all the maps, you can use `flatMap()` to merge their entries into one stream:

```
Map<String, String> preFilteredKafkaRecords = kafkaRecordMap.entrySet().stream()
    .map(item -> getUrls(item.getKey(), item.getValue()))
    .map(Map::entrySet)
    .flatMap(Set::stream)
    .filter(THING_1)
    .filter(THING_2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Alternatively, you can use a custom collector to fold each result into a single map:

```
Map<String, String> preFilteredKafkaRecords = kafkaRecordMap.entrySet().stream()
    .map(item -> getUrls(item.getKey(), item.getValue()))
    .filter(THING_1)
    .filter(THING_2)
    .collect(HashMap::new, Map::putAll, Map::putAll);
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I needed

Comment: Should note your first solution only works in static context

Comment: What do you mean?